# Is UseGCOverheadLimit supported with G1 GC?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, jvm-hotspot, g1gc

In [HotSpot JVM GC Tuning Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/) the `UseGCOverheadLimit` option is mentioned only on the pages about CMS and Parallel GCs. Additionally, on [GC Ergonomics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gc-ergonomics.html) doc page the related options `GCTimeLimit` and `GCHeapFreeLimit` are mentioned like if they work only with Parallel GC:

> The parallel garbage collector (UseParallelGC) throws an out-of-memory exception if an excessive amount of time is being spent collecting a small amount of the heap. To avoid this exception, you can increase the size of the heap. You can also set the parameters -XX:GCTimeLimit=time-limit and -XX:GCHeapFreeLimit=space-limit [...]

Are those options supported with `-XX:+UseG1GC`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GC overhead limit is the feature of [AdaptiveSizePolicy](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/aa4ffb1f30c9/src/share/vm/gc_implementation/shared/adaptiveSizePolicy.cpp#l418), which is used in Parallel GC and CMS, but [not in G1](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/aa4ffb1f30c9/src/share/vm/gc_implementation/g1/g1CollectedHeap.hpp#l1047).

You may also double-check that `gc_overhead_limit_was_exceeded` flag is never set in [`G1CollectedHeap::mem_allocate`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/aa4ffb1f30c9/src/share/vm/gc_implementation/g1/g1CollectedHeap.cpp#l835).

So, `-XX:+UseGCOverheadLimit` does nothing in G1 GC.

Comment: There is actually a RFE created for G1 to support this. See https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8212084