# Is UseGCOverheadLimit supported by ZGC?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, zgc

we are currently using `G1GC` which [does *not* honour/support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45925980/is-usegcoverheadlimit-supported-with-g1-gc/45927722#45927722) `UseGCOverheadLimit`, so our app is sometimes completely stuck in GC-thrashing and the jvm never aborts/crashes.

Just checking which options we do have, [according to this overview](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/gctuning/available-collectors.html#GUID-F215A508-9E58-40B4-90A5-74E29BF3BD3C) the latest GC is [ZGC](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/zgc/Main) but I can't find anything whether `ZGC` actually supports the overhead limit?

Comment: Just few questions to understand the context and how you concluded that the JVM got stuck in GC. 1- What version of Oracle JDK are you using? 2- What JVM options are you using? 3- Did you enable GC log file (**) to understand the behavior of this JVM ? * Given you asked for ZGC (debuted in Java 11), GC log file is enabled with:
a- G1: -Xlog:gc*:time,gc+phases=debug:file=gc.log OR
b- non-G1: -Xlog:gc*:file=gc.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this simple command to verify if that JVM option is enabled:

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -XX:+UseZGC -version | grep -i Overhead
     bool UseGCOverheadLimit                       = true                                      {product} {default}
java version "17.0.3.1" 2022-04-22 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.3.1+2-LTS-6)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.3.1+2-LTS-6, mixed mode, sharing)
```